# When installing a self-hosted GitHub Runner on a Linux machine, who should own the directory and run the runner in /usr/local?

Tags: linux, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I've been following the instructions to install a self-hosted GitHub Runner on a Linux VM. I've created the folder for the GitHub Runner in `/usr/local/actions-runner`, then I changed the owner to my user account (`chmod -R <my user> /usr/local/actions-runner`.) I'm unsure if my user account should be able to run the `run.sh` script, or if it should be a super user or another user.

What is the more secure or otherwise best way to install and run a self-hosted GitHub Runner?